# Linear algebra question on checking equality of subspaces of a given vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve following previous year semester exam question.

> In the vector space $\mathbb{C^3}(\mathbb{C})$ let $W_1$ be a subspace
> generated by the subset $\{(1, 1, 0), (1, i, 1+i)\}$ and $W_2$ be a
> subspace generated by $\{(1, 0, i), (1+i, 1, -1)\}$. Then I have
> to prove that $W_1 = W_2$.

**My attempt:** Let $S_1 = \{(1, 1, 0), (1, i, 1+i)\}$ and $S_2 = \{(1, 0, i), (1+i, 1, -1)\}$.
Initially I tried to check the linear independence of $S_1$ and $S_2$. For this purpose consider the linear combination $a(1, 1, 0) + b(1, i, 1+i) = (0+0i, 0+0i, 0+0i)$, the resulting condition $a = b = 0$, confirms the linear independence of $S_1$. Similarly I checked that $S_2$ is linearly independent.
This shows that $dim W_1 = dim W_2 = 1$, since $S_1$ and $S_2$ are generators of $W_1$ and $W_2$ respectively.

**Doubt** I understand that to prove $W_1 = W_2$ we have to show that $W_1 \subseteq W_2$ or $W_2 \subseteq W_1$. Here I am finding it difficult to proceed. Kindly help me.

Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more general claim (which you are welcome to prove) -

If $W_1 = sp\{v_1, \cdots ,v_n\}$ and $W_2 = sp\{u_1, \cdots ,u_n\}$, and each $v_i \in W_2$ and each $u_i \in W_1$ then $W_1=W_2$.

i.e., it is enough the show dual-sided inclusion only on the spanning set (it does not have to be a base, in general).

In our case, we can indeed see that

$$
v_1 = (1,1,0) = -i * (1, 0, i) + 1 * (1+i, 1, -1) = -i * u_1 + 1 * u_2 \in W_2
$$
$$
v_2 = (1,i,1+i) = (2 - i) * (1, 0, i) + i * (1+i, 1, -1) =(2-i)*u_1+i*u_2\in W_2 
$$

I will leave it to you to find the inverse inclusion.

Regarding how to find to coefficients, either trail and error (try dealing each component one-at-a-time), or put a general coefficients $a,b$, and solve a system of $3$ equations with $2$ unknowns.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. Thanks a lot. I am clear now

Answer (score 2):

We do need the vectors in $W_1$ to be linearly independent for them to be a basis of a vector space.  With two independent vectors, $W_1$ is a 2-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb C^3.$  Same applies for $W_2$

Now for $W_1 = W_2$ we must show that there exists a linear combination of the basis vectors of $W_1$ that will equal each of the basis vectors of $W_2.$  In which case you will have found the transformation from one basis to the other of the same subspace.

$a_1(1,1,0) + b_1(1,i,1+i) = (1,0,i)\\
b_1 = \frac {1+i}{2}\\
a_1(1,1,0) + (\frac {1+i}{2},\frac {-1+i}{2},i) = (1,0,i)\\
a_1 = \frac {1-i}{2}$

$a_2(1,1,0) + b_2(1,i,1+i) = (1+i,1,-1)\\
b_2 = \frac {-1+i}{2}\\
a_2(1,1,0) + (\frac {-1+i}{2},\frac {-1-i}{2},-1) = (1+i,1,-1)\\
a_2 = \frac {3+i}{2}$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not able to show the second part. Thats where I have asked for help.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. Thanks from the bottom of heart.