# Proving $\text{span}\{v_{1}, v_{2} \} = \text{span}\{u_{1}, u_{2} \}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I read this [this link on mathsstack](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1049238/prove-two-sets-span-the-same-subspace) about how to show that  $\text{span}\{v_{1}, v_{2} \} = \text{span}\{u_{1}, u_{2} \}$.  One of the answer is that all you need to show these two sets are subsets of each other.

**My doubt** If instead of this I show that $dim W_1  = dim W_2$, where $ W_1 =\text{span}\{v_{1}, v_{2} \}$ and $W_2 = \text{span}\{u_{1}, u_{2} \}$ and $W_1 \subseteq W_2$ or $W_2 \subseteq W_1$. Then can't I claim that $\text{span}\{v_{1}, v_{2} \} = \text{span}\{u_{1}, u_{2} \}$. Similar question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4833781/linear-algebra-question-on-checking-equality-of-subspaces-of-a-given-vector-spac). What I think is we dont't need to check $W_1 \subseteq W_2$ and vicerversa. I am not having any reference to support my claim or proof. Kindly clear my doubt.

Thanks a lot for any kind of help.

Comment: Are you claiming that if two subspaces have the same dimention, then they are equal? Is that your question?

Comment: @QuantumSuperfield That is not the question. If $dim W_1 = dim W_2$ and $W_1\subset W_2$ then can we say that $W_1 =W _2$? Thanks for the response.

Comment: It is a well-known fact that if $V$ is finite-dimensional and $U$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $\dim U=\dim V$, then $U=V$. For this reason, if  $W_1 \subseteq W_2$ and $\dim W_1  = \dim W_2$, where $ W_1 =\text{span}\{v_{1}, v_{2} \}$ and $W_2 = \text{span}\{u_{1}, u_{2} \}$, we can conclude that $W_1=W_2$.

Comment: @QuantumSuperfield Thank you so much. Now my doubt is completely clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you show only that $W_1\subset W_2$ and that both have same dimensions, then yes you can conclude that the spaces are equal. The reason is that if you take a basis of $W_1$ made of $n$ vectors ($n$ being the common dimension, at most 2 for you), then these vectors are linearly independent in $W_2$ too, so they make a basis of this space too. Hence they generate it too.